# Python: How to do looping multiplication and discard those binary value 0?

Tags: python, csv, binary, multiplication, python-itertools

I have binary values filled in a csv file and a list of real number values that I would like to apply multiplication on both files. How can I discard those values which multiply with the value of 0 in csv file? Can anyone help me with the algorithm part?

**Binary.csv**

This is 3 lines binary values.

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

**Real.csv**

This is one line real number values.

```
0.1 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.5 0.5 0.3 0.6 0.3
```

**Before desired output**

```
0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.6 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0
```

**Desired output**

```
0.2 0.5 0.3
0.1 0.5 0.6
0.4 0.5 0.3
```

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = np.array([[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]])
b = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.3])
c=(a * b)

d=itertools.compress(c,str(True))
print d
```

The above code is just another alternatives that I tried at the same time. Sorry for inconvenience. Very appreciate all your helps here.

Comment: So you have a comma separated file separated by blanks?

Comment: Also what's the problem? Reading the file? Writing the file? Doing the multiplication? Macaroni?

Comment: It is in excel file format.

Comment: See [**`itertools.compress`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)

Comment: Where the heck did numpy arrays come from?  You said you were using CSV files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to do this, mine is simplistic:

```
import csv

with open('real.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' '):
        reals = row

with open('binary.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    pwreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    for row in pwreader:
        result = []
        for i,b in enumerate(row):
            if b == '1' :
                result.append(reals[i])

        print " ".join(result)
```

You will notice that there is no multiplication here.  When you read from a CSV file the values are strings.  You could convert each field to a numeric, construct a bit-mask, then work it out from there, but is it worth it?  I have just used a simple string comparison.  The output is a string anyway.

Edit:  now I find you have numpy arrays in your code, ignoring the csv files.  Please stop changing the goalposts!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.